# Is there any clean way of initializing an object with a variable key?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two variable, `attribute` (e.g. "type") and `value` (e.g. "car"). I want to make an object where the key is the attribute (and the value is the value). Like this: `{"type": "car"}`.

When I do

```
let obj = { attribute: value }
```

I get

```
> {"attribute": "car"}
```

This is easy with two lines, as I can just

```
let obj = {};
obj[attribute] = value;
```

However, I'm wondering if there is a clean way of doing this in one line (since I'm a former Rubyist and I like making things clean and precise)?

Comment: (Also I feel this is a question that already has an answer here, but I could not find a similar question, so I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate)

Comment: See the bottom of the accepted answer in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), starting from ES2015 aka ES6.

```js
let a = "type", b = "car";
console.log({[a]: b});
```

Comment: PERFECT! I knew there had to be something, but my coworkers and I were stumped.

Comment: @MikeManfrin be aware that this won't necessarily work everywhere, at least for now.

Comment: We're thankfully using typescript -> es6, so this should work for us, thank you!